# Ordering of error output

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Main
{
    public static int quotient(int a, int b) throws ArithmeticException
    {
        return a / b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean continueLoop = true;

        do
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.print("Enter integer numerator: ");
                int numerator = scan.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Enter integer denomiantor: ");
                int denominator = scan.nextInt();

                int result = quotient(numerator, denominator);
                System.out.println("Result: " + numerator + " / " + denominator
                        + " = " + result);
                continueLoop = false;
            } 

            catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException)
            {
                System.err.println("\nException: " + inputMismatchException);
                scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\nSolution: Must enter an integer");
            }

            catch (ArithmeticException arithmeticException)
            {
                System.err.println("\nException" + arithmeticException);
                System.out.println("Solution: Zero is an invalid denominator");
            }
        } while (continueLoop);
    }
}
```

---

Output:

```
Enter integer numerator: 5
Enter integer denomiantor: 0
Solution: Zero is an invalid denominator
Enter integer numerator: 
Exceptionjava.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

I'm confused on why did the `System.err.println` message was displayed at the end? And also why does an infinite loop occurs if I leave out `scan.nextLine();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One at a time:

> I'm confused on why did the System.err.println message was displayed at the end?

The *output* stream goes directly to your console. The *error* stream is buffered during execution, and is flushed when the program terminates. Hence it's appearing at the end.

> And also why does an infinite loop occurs if I leave out scan.nextLine();?

It's still 'scanning' the previous line if you don't, always finding invalid integers, always throwing the exception, never getting to the point where `continueLoop` becomes `false`.